# TranslateZ give me no result

Tags: css, css-transforms

Heei. I just trying to use `transform: translateZ(value);`. When I try like this https://codepen.io/bariq_dharmawan/pen/yEPaxw

I confused why `translateZ(0px)` still make something change on the element. Please, I need some explaination

[image]

On image above, the transparancy of background-color looks like reduced when I hover. I don't know why

Comment: Can you describe what you see changing in the codepen, and in which browser?

Comment: On chrome latest version (Ubuntu), the element looks like more transparant (something like you change the opacity to 0.5) @MrLister

Comment: I don't see it, sorry I tried several version of Chrome, between v57 and v69, on multiple OSes, but I don't see any difference when hovering.

Comment: I just updated my question for better explaination with result, please see :) @MrLister

Comment: It's coming just fine for me too. Tested on Chrome (69), Firefox, Safari. `translateZ` should not have any affect on opacity.

Comment: ... and even if it did, the default value is 0px anyway ([link](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms)), so setting it explicitly to 0px has no effect.

Comment: @MrLister Not exactly ... Default value for transform is none. Setting a translateZ(0px) can have side effects, like displaying  the element through the GPU instead of the CPU. So eventually, this could be an issue about some problem in the GPU of the OP

Comment: @vals but I still don't get it how to use `translateZ` . Can you give me some example or resource about it?

Comment: @BariqDharmawan It's part of `translated3d`, and it will only have a visible effect if the element also has other 3D properties, like `perspective`. [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeZVeB). You should look up "translate3d".

Comment: Okk, thank you @MrLister !